# get Not enough information to infer type variable T when initializing kotlin raw types

Tags: kotlin, generics

I tried to write raw types for. kotlin in a class and initialized the raw type

```
class RawType {
  
  interface I<T : RawType?> {
    fun f(t: T) {}
  }

  class RawSubclass: I<T: RawType?> {
    override fun f(t: RawType?) {}
  }
  fun test() {
    val unbound = Unbound<T: RawType?>()
  }

}
```

the java I can write

```
class RawType {
  
  interface I<T extends RawType> {
    default void f(T t) {}
  }

  class BoundRecursively<T extends BoundRecursively<T>> {}

  static class RawSubclass implements I {
    @Override
    public void f(RawType t) {}
  }
  test() {
    Unbound unbound = new Unbound();
    
  }
}
```

but it gives error `Expecting a '>' Expecting member declaration` for line `class RawSubclass: I<T: RawType?>`  and `Not enough information to infer type variable T` for `val unbound = Unbound<T: RawType?>()`. Any suggestion why the error occurs and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: what is this Unbound type? can you add it in your question's code?

Comment: it does not have any type. This is the java code and I need to convert it to kotlin. Thanks